# Persistence Through Segues

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm trying to understand persistence through segues in Swift. I have three text fields, let's call them name, date, and location all in a single view. I am creating a two view form, so after I collect those data points (name, date, location) I'm using a segue to transition to the next view via a button added to the first view.

I have then added a back button on the next view to return to the original view (w/ the name, date, location fields). What I don't understand is how those values in the fields are persisting. I have not added any delegates or added any connection with the second view controller. However, when I return to the first view controller from the second, the values (name, date, location) are persisting in their respective text fields. But if I add something to the second view controllers text fields, return to the first and then move forward back to the second, those values in the second are not persisting.

```
class pageOne: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var location: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var date: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {}

    @IBAction func nextScreen(sender: UIButton) {

        if(eventLocation.text != nil){
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("firstSegue", sender: self)

        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Location", message:"Please enter a new location.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}



class pageTwo: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var firstValue: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondValue: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
    }

    @IBAction func backToStart(sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("firstSegueReturn", sender: self) 
    }
}
```

Is the segue maintaining the prior state of the view? Is that why I see the values I have entered in the first view when I return back to it through the "firstSegueReturn"? But then why isn't the data in the second views text fields being saved when I return back to it from the first?

Comment: The answer is in your text. You segue to something new, and go back to where you came from. Hence segue forward is to a new controller whose content is defined by what you set as the default content or in your `prepareForSegue` method. When you go back, you go back to where you came from which has all the original content. So think of the view controllers as being created and stacked up as you segue forward and being popped off and thrown away going backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So iOS maintains a navigation stack.  When you segue to your second view, the first view is still on the navigation stack so it remains in memory.  When you go back to your first view from the second, the second view is popped off the memory stack and no longer has memory allocated for it. That's why when you return to the second view controller your values are no longer there.

Hope that clears things up.